# Pygame: Charachter invincibility taking 2 damage instead of 1

Tags: python, pygame

So, i'm making a game in Pygame for a school project. Right now, I have my character who collides with an enemy. I have invincibility once the player gets hit, but for some reason for the first hit the player takes 2 damage, and then the timer works and they player has temporary invincibility.

Player Class Code:

```
vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, Game,bullet):
            pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.Game = Game
            self.image = pg.image.load('idle.png')
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (screenWidth / 2, screenLength / 2)
            self.pos = vec(screenWidth / 2, screenLength / 2)
            self.vel = vec(0, 0)
            self.acc = vec(0,0)
            self.health = 3
            self.ammo = 10
            self.cooldown = 700
            self.bullet = bullet
            self.timer = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.itimer = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.left = False
            self.right = False
            self.invincin = False
            self.invincinCoolDown= 1300
```

Enemy Class(ignore the end variable):

```
class enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,end):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load("enemy.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.alive = True
        self.health = 3
        self.end = end
        self.speed = 1
        self.timer = pg.time.get_ticks()
```

Heres my code for when the player get hits(Invincin is incibility):

```
if pHits:
     if self.player.invincin == False:
     self.health -= 1
     self.player.invincin = True
```

Heres my code for invincibility:

```
        if self.player.invincin == True:
            inow = pg.time.get_ticks()
            if inow - self.player.itimer >= self.player.invincinCoolDown:
                self.player.itimer = inow
                self.player.invincin = False
```

Heres my Code for Collision:

```
pHits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player,self.all_enemy, False, False)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the full code. But maybe I see possible problem. In your code:

```
if pHits and self.player.invincin == False:
```

I conclude that you want this condition to pass when both are False but this condition passes when `pHits == True` and `self.player.invincin == False`. Maybe try to change this first if I assumed correctly.

Comment: I added more code. I tried splitting up the code but it didn't work.

Comment: I thought that maybe you wanted both `pHits` and `self.player.invincin` to be False in order to pass the condition.
Sorry, can't see the problem. I will need the full code in order to try to help.